# Unity - Progress bar with sprites

Tags: unity, sprites

I have 4 images that I made in photoshop that represent the progress the player is making in the game. When you finish the first level the image changes, when you finish the second level changes again, and so on.

But I have no idea how to make that work. So anything helps. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you know when a level is finished? Do you store this information somewhere? In a file maybe? [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @Hellium also, if someone knows how to change a sprite from code and they know how to recognize when a player "finished the current part of the level", it should be simple to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this we need to use what's called Image, which is a 2d sprite that we render for our ui:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html
 One way you coul make this work in a scrilt is by having a list of all the images that you created in photoshop, and then just switch the sprite of the object with one of the images from the list